# Clojure - How to put a list and a function inside a defn function

Tags: function, clojure, defn

I am a newbie and making some exercises. How can I put a `def` with a list of sentences and a randomizer function inside a `defn` function? How does that work?

`(def list["test1", "test2", "test3"])` - works fine
`(rand-nth list)` - works fine

How do I put it inside a function `defn`?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'd say, use `let`, but it's really not that clear, what you mean by "put inside a defn".  Could you maybe add what you have tried and how it failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you just want to reimplement `rand-nth`, no?

```clj
(defn wrapped-rand-nth [a-list]
  (rand-nth a-list))
```

If you want the list to be static (non-changing)

```clj
(defn randomize []
  (rand-nth ["test1" "test2" "test3"]))
```

works, but it creates the vector upon each call, a better way is to

```clj
(let [the-list ["test1" "test2" "test3"]]
  (defn randomize []
    (rand-nth the-list)))
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted - second option. Thank You .  : )